# How to run transactional SQL on Redshift using boto3

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to use boto3 redshift-data client to execute transactional SQL for external table (Redshift spectrum) with following statement,

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD IF NOT EXISTS
PARTITION(key=value)
LOCATION 's3://bucket/prefix';
```

After submit using `execute_statement`, I received error **"ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE cannot run inside a transaction block"**.

I tried use `VACUUM` and `COMMIT` commands before the statement, but it will just mention that `VACUUM` or `COMMIT` cannot run inside a transaction block.

How may I successfully execute such statement?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the settings of your bench.  You have an open transaction at the start of every statement you run.  Just add “END;” before the statement that needs to run outside of a transaction and things should work.  Just make sure you launch both commands at the same time from your bench.

Like this:

```
END; VACUUM;
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work if using `boto3` in an automation set up.  But I found a workaround with `redshift_connector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not quite easy to run transactional SQL through boto3.  However, I found a workaround using the `redshift_connector` library.

```
import redshift_connector

connection = redshift_connector.connect(
    host=host, port=port, database=database, user=user, password=password
)

connection.autocommit = True
connection.cursor.execute(transactional_sql)
connection.autocommit = False
```

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html#python-connect-enable-autocommit